# How to display clicked option as default in dropdown selector

Tags: html, liquid

I'm setting up a currency selector and I want it to display the currency which was chosen even when the page reloads. It always defaults back to displaying USD.

I have looked into ways to display a default but have only found ways to select one option as the default. I want the default to be whatever was last clicked on, not one set option.

```
<select id="multicurrency-selector">
    <li>{% for link in linklists.currency.links %}
        <option value="{{ link.url }}">{{ link.title }}</option>
    {% endfor %}</li>
</select>

<script>
    document.getElementById("multicurrency-selector").onchange = function() {
    if (this.selectedIndex!==0) {
        window.location.href = this.value;
    }
        };
</script>
```

Comment: Unrelated, but remove the `<li>` tags surrounding your `<option>`, that's invalid HTML.

Comment: If you want to persist whatever the user chose, you can place the option in a cookie `document.cookie = 'currency=somevalue';` and then you can read it on document load.

Comment: Thanks @jake2389 for your reply. Sorry I'm a bit of a newbie to code really, I'm unsure where to add this suggestion.